# What is a Rosalina and Luma true combo that is easy to learn?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I recently found out that I am really good with Rosalina, but I can't seem to get any good combos to step up my game with her. What are some easy to learn true combos for Rosalina and Luma?

As per the [Super Smash Brothers Wiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com) [page on Combos](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Combo); a true combo is a combo that keeps the enemy player in a hitstun.

Comment: "True combo", meaning...?

Comment: A true combo is a combo that works 100% of the time. Such as Mario's down throw to up tilt, to up b. Eventually this won't work at percents such as 55%+ but by then you don't really need it.

Comment: taken from the super smash wiki; "Any sequence of attacks that keeps the opponent in hitstun. These are commonly known as true combos."

Comment: Rolling back to include the request for a true combo, as a true combo is actually defined in ssb, and I believe it was taken out under misinterpretation of OPs opinion of said combos.

Comment: Do you want reputable sources for some combos, or are you open to experimentation and posting of 2 cents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be very helpful, but downthrow to up tilt is very good. When you have luma its even better. At lower percent up smash works too!